# A physics problem? Hmm... Let's see

Tags: situation

I've made this up and I have no idea how easy or difficult it is.

---

Person A has two objects B and C. A performs an experiment in her living room. She places a 100cm high solid wooden box in the centre of the room and continues as follows.

A stands on the 100cm high box and holds each of the objects in turn, away from the box at a total height of 200cm.

1. A drops B onto the solid, flat, horizontal surface of her living room floor. B bounces several times and comes to rest immediately below where it was dropped from.
2. A then drops C in exactly the same way with all the same starting conditions. C strikes the floor but does not bounce. C comes to rest on top of the box that A was standing on.

**Question**

Can you explain?

Hint

> A is Anna. B is a ball. What is C?

---

***Note**
B is removed before continuing the experiment with C. C does not bounce off B. B and C do not come into contact at all.*

Comment: Has the [[tag:physics]] tag been deliberately left out?

Comment: @bobble - Well there is an argument for including it but then everything that happens in the natural world involves physics so it seems superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A is Anna. B is a ball. Maybe C is

> a Cat?
>  So friendly and forgiving that it doesn't mind being dropped to the floor and comes to rest at its owner's feet?
>  (it might be an automated cat then)